# Error Clip Raster by Mask layer

Tags: qgis, clip

I just want to clip the raster by vector layer for the specific area, however I get this error after running. How to fix this?

```
QGIS version: 3.28.15-Firenze
QGIS code revision: 252ad49ddc
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.18
GDAL version: 3.8.3
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.1, December 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: 3fced5)
Algorithm started at: 2024-03-19T21:42:44
Algorithm 'Clip raster by mask layer' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'DATA_TYPE' : 0, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/MRW_DEM.tif', 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'MASK' : 'C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/Elevation/sw5.shp', 'MULTITHREADING' : False, 'NODATA' : None, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/Elevation/SW5.tif', 'SET_RESOLUTION' : False, 'SOURCE_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32651'), 'TARGET_CRS' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32651'), 'TARGET_EXTENT' : None, 'X_RESOLUTION' : None, 'Y_RESOLUTION' : None }
```

GDAL command:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:32651 -t_srs EPSG:32651 -of GTiff -cutline C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/Elevation/sw5.shp -cl sw5 -crop_to_cutline C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/MRW_DEM.tif C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/Elevation/SW5.tif
GDAL command output:
Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 782127.5 784972.5
ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
Process returned error code 1
Execution completed in 0.19 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/Elevation/SW5.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• C:/Users/kirkw/Documents/THESIS/qgis/Elevation/SW5.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your polygon is invalid as it has a self intersection. First you need to clean your geometry layer. From processing tools select `Vector Geometry > Fix Geometries` and `Run`. This will create a new layer after fixing the geometry errors.